# Issue with 'pandas on spark' used with conda: "No module named 'pyspark.pandas'" even though both pyspark and pandas are installed

Tags: pandas, pyspark, modulenotfounderror

I have installed both Spark 3.1.3 and Anaconda 4.12.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I have set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to be the python bin of a conda environment called `my_env`

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python
```

I installed several packages on conda environment `my_env` using `pip`. Here is a portion of the output of `pip freeze` command:

```
numpy==1.22.3
pandas==1.4.1
py4j==0.10.9.3
pyarrow==7.0.0
```

**N.B:** package `pyspark` is not installed on the conda environment `my_env`. I would like to be able to launch a pyspark shell on different conda environments without having to reinstall `pyspark` in every environment (I would like to only modify `PYSPARK_PYTHON`). This would also avoids having different versions of Spark on different conda environments (which is sometimes desirable but not always).

When I launch a pyspark shell using `pyspark` command, I can indeed import `pandas` and `numpy` which confirms that `PYSPARK_PYTHON` is properly set (`my_env` is the only conda env with `pandas` and `numpy` installed, moreover `pandas` and `numpy` are not installed on any other python installation even outside conda, and finally if I change `PYSPARK_PYTHON` I am no longer able to import `pandas` or `numpy`).

Inside the pyspark shell, the following code works fine (creating and showing a toy Spark dataframe):

```
sc.parallelize([(1,2),(2,4),(3,5)]).toDF(["a", "b"]).show()
```

However, if I try to convert the above dataframe into a [**pandas on spark**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html) dataframe it does not work. The command

```
sc.parallelize([(1,2),(2,4),(3,5)]).toDF(["t", "a"]).to_pandas_on_spark()
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_pandas_on_spark'
```

I tried to *first* import `pandas` (which works fine) and *then* `pyspark.pandas` *before* running the above command but when I run

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

I obtain the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.pandas'
```

Any idea why this happens ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html), it seems that you need apache spark 3.2, not 3.1.3. Update to 3.2 and you will have the desired API.

Comment: Good point! It works! Thanks!

Comment: You welcome. Please mark it as solved @RonanFruit so others know it's a valid solution

Comment: still happening for me with 3.2 or 3.3

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyspark #need spark 3.3 
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```